# react development server not starting

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npx

I make a react app using the command "npx create-react-app" and I try to start the development server without doing any changes to it using "npm start" and it ends with this error

picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r28sS.png

and this is the log file

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'start'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.1.0
2 info using node@v16.13.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 3ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:T:\t\Projects\React.js\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 3ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\thevi\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\thevi\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 14ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 14ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
21 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 0ms
22 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 4ms
23 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 7ms
24 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
25 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 1ms
26 timing npm:load Completed in 31ms
27 timing command:run-script Completed in 3ms
28 timing command:start Completed in 16ms
29 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'T:\t\Projects\React.js\package.json'
30 verbose cwd T:\t\Projects\React.js
31 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22000
32 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
33 verbose node v16.13.0
34 verbose npm  v8.1.0
35 error code ENOENT
36 error syscall open
37 error path T:\t\Projects\React.js/package.json
38 error errno -4058
39 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'T:\t\Projects\React.js\package.json'
40 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
41 verbose exit -4058
```

Comment: "...with this error"? what is the error? so we could help you

Comment: Change your directory to where you created your React app first. `cd anatha_1 && npm start`

Comment: I think there is a problem with package.json, can you show your files-directories and package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first go to your project directory, in your case it is called `anatha_1`.

So, run `cd anatha_1`, then `npm start`.

`npm start` or any other npm script, looks for the package.json file in the current working directory.

It is also what is written by `create-react-app` at the end of its output, so please follow the guidelines.